# How do I redirect after ajax request in angularjs?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, node.js

I am using angularjs and nodejs for my project. Now after I do my authentication using background call. Now after I receive my successful authentication, how do I redirect the user to dashboard? Here is my login div:

```
  <div ng-controller="loginCtrl" class="control">
    <form role="form" name="docRegForm" ng-submit="login()" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-xs-11 div-center">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="exampleInputEmail1" type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="exampleInputPassword1" type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 div-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger full-width">LOGIN</button>
```

And my angular controller is:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
  $scope.message = '';

  $scope.login = function () {
    $http
      .post('/authenticate', $scope.user)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $window.localStorage.nimbusToken = data.token;
        console.log($window.localStorage.token);
        $scope.message = 'Welcome';  
        };
        alerts[data.status];
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // Erase the token if the user fails to log in
        alert("failure");
        delete $window.localStorage.token;
        // Handle login errors here
        $scope.message = 'Error: Invalid user or password';
      });
  };
});
```

Now after the login, I have to redirect to dashboard or to relogin, if failed login. How do I do that?

Comment: use $location.path('/')..

Comment: i tried that. but only the url in address bar changes. but the page does not navigate.

Comment: than try: window.location.href = "your path";

Comment: or use: window.location.replace("your path.");

Comment: yep... thanks a lot. Both did the trick. which one is better approach? setting the window.location.href or replacing window.location.replace()?

Comment: you can use anyone of them. I am posting those as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$location.path('')`, not works for you, than try these:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect

window.location.replace("your path.");
```

or:

```
 window.location.replace("your path.")
```

Comment: This will reload the whole page.

Comment: Try `window.location = "your_path"`
Or just `$state.go('your_path')`.
`$state.go` is preferred, because it's only change the route and not reload the whole page

Answer (score 1):

In success use:-

$location.path("/dashboard");

In error use:-

$location.path("/login");

Comment: I did that and only the url in the address bar changes, but does not redirect.